# How can I eliminate the duplicate subqueries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I eliminate the duplicate subqueries?

```
SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU )
```

from the following query below:

```
Declare @OPV int
Declare @Today_JD int
Declare @DayOfWeek int
SET  @Today_JD =  dbo.date2jde (convert(varchar(10),getdate(),111)) --today in Julian   
SET  @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, dbo.jde2date(@Today_JD))    -- Day of week (1 to 7)

UPDATE TESTDTA.F4211  SET SDVR03 = 1
FROM TESTDTA.F4211

WHERE sdkcoo = 30001 and sdsrp1 = 'ITO' and sdsobk > 0 and  sdvend > '' and 
      sddoco = 2606544 and sdlnid = 27000 and 

    CASE 
        WHEN ((SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD) AND (@DayOfWeek = 2) and (SDVEND= 1010 OR SDVEND=4010)) THEN 1
            WHEN ((SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD) AND (@DayOfWeek = 3) and (SDVEND= 110051 OR SDVEND=110052 OR SDVEND = 2010)) THEN 1            
            WHEN ((SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD) AND (@DayOfWeek = 4) and (SDVEND= 50001))   THEN 1
            WHEN ((SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD) AND (@DayOfWeek = 5) and (SDVEND= 110034))  THEN 1    
        ELSE 0      
    END  = 1
```

Comment: I couldnt get the query format right. I posted it now.

Comment: This should work: WHEN ((SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD) AND ((@DayOfWeek = 2 and (SDVEND= 1010 OR SDVEND=4010)) OR (@DayOfWeek = 3 and (SDVEND= 110051 OR SDVEND=110052 OR SDVEND = 2010) OR (@DayOfWeek = 4 and (SDVEND= 50001)) OR (@DayOfWeek = 5 and (SDVEND= 110034))) THEN 1                                           Thanks

Comment: @user624128: `SDVEND IN (1010, 4010)` seems more convenient than `SDVEND= 1010 OR SDVEND=4010`.

Comment: @user624128 - you should not use a CASE statement for something so trivial

Answer (score 1):

Simple really, remove it from the CASE clauses and put directly into the WHERE clause.  If it is not true, ALL branches of the CASE statement goes to FALSE -> it ends up with CASE ELSE -> 0 which won't match the `= 1` at the end.  So just take it outside of the case.

```
Declare @OPV int
Declare @Today_JD int
Declare @DayOfWeek int
SET  @Today_JD =  dbo.date2jde (convert(varchar(10),getdate(),111)) --today in Julian   
SET  @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, dbo.jde2date(@Today_JD))    -- Day of week (1 to 7)

UPDATE TESTDTA.F4211  SET SDVR03 = 1
FROM TESTDTA.F4211
WHERE sdkcoo = 30001 and sdsrp1 = 'ITO' and sdsobk > 0 and  sdvend > '' and 
      sddoco = 2606544 and sdlnid = 27000 and 
      (SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD)
AND
    CASE 
        WHEN (@DayOfWeek = 2) and SDVEND IN (1010,4010) THEN 1
        WHEN (@DayOfWeek = 3) and SDVEND IN (110051,110052,2010) THEN 1            
        WHEN (@DayOfWeek = 4) and SDVEND= 50001)   THEN 1
        WHEN (@DayOfWeek = 5) and SDVEND= 110034)  THEN 1    
        ELSE 0      
    END  = 1
```

I would go further and drop the case statement completely

```
Declare @OPV int
Declare @Today_JD int
Declare @DayOfWeek int
SET  @Today_JD =  dbo.date2jde (convert(varchar(10),getdate(),111)) --today in Julian   
SET  @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, dbo.jde2date(@Today_JD))    -- Day of week (1 to 7)

UPDATE TESTDTA.F4211  SET SDVR03 = 1
FROM TESTDTA.F4211
WHERE sdkcoo = 30001 and sdsrp1 = 'ITO' and sdsobk > 0 and  sdvend > '' and 
      sddoco = 2606544 and sdlnid = 27000 and 
      ((SDPDDJ - (SELECT IBOPV FROM TESTDTA.F4102 WHERE IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU ) >= @Today_JD)
AND (
    ((@DayOfWeek = 2) and SDVEND IN (1010,4010)) OR
    ((@DayOfWeek = 3) and SDVEND IN (110051,110052,2010)) OR
    ((@DayOfWeek = 4) and (SDVEND= 50001)) OR
    ((@DayOfWeek = 5) and (SDVEND= 110034))
    )
```

Comment: I cleaned up the CASE statement. Now it looks neat. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL Servers `update ... from` syntax, like:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     SDVR03 = 1
FROM    TESTDTA.F4211 t1
JOIN    TESTDTA.F4102 t2
ON      IBLITM = SDLITM and IBMCU = SDMCU
WHERE   ...
```